Svelte on:click called on load
In my Svelte component why is the on:click={checkItem} event being called when the component is mounted?
Item.svelte:
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    export let item;

    $: icon = item.checked ? "check_box" : "check_box_outline_blank";

    function checkItem() {
        item.checked = !item.checked;

        dispatch("clicked");
    }
</script>

<section class="card">
    <div class="inputRow">
        <i on:click={checkItem} class="material-icons">{icon}</i>

        <p>{item.name}</p>

        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
    </div>
</section>

In the parent component I just listen to the event and log "click".
List.svelte (parent):
{#each items as item}
    <Item bind:item on:clicked={console.log("click")} />
{/each}

This prints "click" to the console when the component is loaded but not when I click the icon.
I want the checkItem function to run only when the icon is clicked.

"This prints "click" to the console when the component is loaded but not when I click the icon." - because you are executing the function console.log("click") right there in that place, instead of passing a function reference.

@CBroe of course totally overlooked that, thanks
